# Entity Framework - Specify Id for a class without changing the class

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to store email message formats in my `DbContext` as so:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MailMessage> MessageFormats { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to use it, I get an exception because `MailMessage` doesn't have an Id. Can I specify an Id for MailMessage or do I have to create a subclass of it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to store `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` objects in your database using EntityFramework? I've only ever seen people store their own classes.  Your best option would be to create your own class that takes a MailMessage in its constructor and exposes the properties you want to save.